# Continue statement inside while loop for search page feature

Tags: php, loops, while-loop, continue

I don't understand why this loop isn't working.

This loop's purpose is simply just to skip every value of the array (in this example, 0-2) that's not equal to the given search term (in this example, TN). So the output should be

```
TN
```

and shouldn't be

```
IN
TN
OH
```

Here's my code:

```
<?php

$states = array('IN', 'TN', 'OH');
$search = 'TN';

$count = 0;
while($count <= count($states)){
    if($states[$count] != $search){
        continue;
    }

    echo $states[$count]."<br/>";
    $count++;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

move the count++ so it always increments and be optimistic:

```
while($count < count($states)){
  if($states[$count] == $search){
    echo $states[$count]."<br/>";
  }
  $count++;
}
```

Comment: But if I make the increment happen before the echo'ing of the state wont that skip the first value set at 0?

Comment: may i recommend array_search?  $pos = array_search($search, $states);
echo $states[$pos]."<br/>";

Comment: i think i should be while($count < count($states)){ remove "=" otherwise it give you error , undefine offser

Answer (score 2):

use  [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

Search an array for the value "TN" and return its key

```
    <?php

       $states = array('IN', 'TN', 'OH'); 
       $search = 'TN'; 

        $index = array_search($search, $states); 

        if($index && $states[$index])
        {

         echo $states[$index];

        }

     ?>
```

Comment: Can it be used like... if(!array_search($search, $states)){continue;} inside my while loop?

Comment: no, with array_search you don't need a loop.  you just go directly to what you need by searching.  $pos = array_search($search, $states); echo $states[$pos]."<br/>";

Comment: there is no need while loop

Answer (score 0):

array_search is best solution for you

```
<?php
$states = array('IN', 'TN', 'OH');
$search = 'TN';
$searcharr = array_search($search, $states); 
var_dump($searcharr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You stuck yourself in an infinite loop.

> 1st iteration while 0 < 3, if $states[0] != 'TN' continue to next
>   iteration $count still 0
>
> 2nd iterantion    while 0 < 3, if $states[0] != 'TN' continue to next
>   iteration $count still 0
>
> ....... ....... .......
>
> And it continues forever You stuck yourself in checking against 0 index.

You should exit the while loop using break once you found your match rather then incrementing count. Also before using `continue` you should increment `$count` variable. Also your while loop condition should be `<` rather than `<=` because `count` returns 3, and your `$states` array indexes are `0,1,2`

```
$states = array('IN', 'TN', 'OH');
$search = 'TN';

$count = 0;
while($count < count($states)){
    if($states[$count] != $search){
        $count++;
        continue;
    }

    echo $states[$count]."<br/>";
    break;
}
```

And you can check [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) & [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to finding an element in an array rather than re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

I think a foreach loop will be a better solution than the while loop. It doesn't need a `cointinue` or a `break` point and doesn't need to count to iterate through the array.

The while loop in this case seems useless.

i.e. :

```
foreach ($states as $state) {
    if ($state == $search) {
        echo $state."<br />";
    }
}
```

Output :

> TN

But the best solution stays the `array_search()`.

Hope it helps.